# Querying remote SPARQL end points using FedX

Tags: java, rdf, sparql

I was trying to create a remote federation using FedX. Below is my code. The first triple pattern gives result when run on the "semantic web dog food" SPARQL end point while the second triple pattern runs on the DBPedia SPARQL endpoint. Can anyone kindly explain what is wrong with the code ? I tried the query and got a 406 error. I am connecting to the internet without any proxy.

```
package Query;

import java.net.Authenticator;
import java.net.PasswordAuthentication;

import org.openrdf.query.QueryLanguage;
import org.openrdf.query.TupleQuery;
import org.openrdf.query.TupleQueryResult;
import org.openrdf.repository.Repository;

import com.fluidops.fedx.Config;
import com.fluidops.fedx.FedXFactory;
import com.fluidops.fedx.FederationManager;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class QueryFedX {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try
        {
            Config.initialize();
            Repository repo = FedXFactory.initializeSparqlFederation(Arrays.asList(
                    "http://dbpedia.org/sparql",
                    "http://data.semanticweb.org/sparql"
                    ));
            String q = "SELECT ?y ?z WHERE { <http://data.semanticweb.org/organization/university-of-oxford> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> ?z . ?y <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/P373> ?z .}";
            TupleQuery query = repo.getConnection().prepareTupleQuery(QueryLanguage.SPARQL, q);
            TupleQueryResult res = query.evaluate();

            while (res.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(res.next());
            }

            FederationManager.getInstance().shutDown();
            System.out.println("Done.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: HTTP 406 indicates one of the endpoints can not provide the syntax format your client is asking for. Have you tried figuring out which of the endpoints is causing the error, e.g. by running this code with only one endpoint in the FedX federation?

Comment: Also, having had a quick look at your profile, it seems you have asked a lot of questions but have never taken the trouble to accept any answers that have been helpful to you. You might want to remedy that.

Comment: Hi Jeen, extremely sorry for not being able to contribute. I will remedy that in future. I was trying with two end points and on both the end points the query "select ?x where { ?x ?y ?z . }" gave me results but when I am trying to run it on both the end points it is giving me a 406 error. I could not understand this behaviour from the remote end point ?

Comment: When you tested with each end point separately, did you use the same code (that is, did you create a FedX federation with a single member to test)? 

More generally: I don't quite know what's going on either and I can't find any online documentation or code examples for FedX. With that in mind, perhaps you're better off contacting the developers directly instead of asking via SO - it's pretty product-specific I think.

Comment: If you decide to contact the developers and they provide an answer, could you come back here and share that answer, so others with a similar problem can also benefit?

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you are running into the same problem we already discussed in [1] and [2]: recently the public DBpedia endpoint changed the permissions to not allow SPARQL ASK queries any longer. Since FedX relies on SPARQL ASK queries for source selection, you are seeing the HTTP errors.

In FedX 3.1 we have addressed this issue (see [2]) and optionally use SELECT queries to determine sources. Are you already using FedX 3.1? Please have a look at the bundled documentation and the referenced threads for details. Also, please let us know if this solves the problem.

References

[1] https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/iwb-discussion/Fb6SwQRWdv4

[2] https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/iwb-discussion/aIHtzvNk4v0